# Best way to tokenize input

Tags: java, sql, tokenize

I'm trying to tokenize input to a program with something like the following:

```
create table users schema {firstName: string, lastName: string, age:number, address: string}
insert on users values {firstName: foo, lastName: bar, age:1, address: 32 foobar street}
```

I want the tokens to come out as the following:

```
Token 1: insert
Token 2: on
Token 3: users
Token 4: values
Token 5: {firstName: foo, lastName: bar, age:1, address: 32 foobar street}
```

It is an SQL-like syntax I'm attempting to use. Is regex the best way or is there something else?

Comment: Right off the bat for me I would suggest regex.  Though I've only know a little in java so there may be something better.

Comment: Why is token 5 `{firstName: foo, lastName: bar, age:1, address: 32 foobar street}`? Wouldn't it be more like `Token 5: '{', Token 6: firstName, Token 7: ':', ...`?

Comment: Also what happened to the `create table` line? Why is it not included in the tokens?

Comment: @Jashaszun the OP provided an example for the second line, not the first...

Comment: first split with delimiter '{', then split the first half of the string with space as delimiter.
If you can change the text within the braces to not have space, then one step operation - split on spaces.

Comment: You can do both those things in one regex statement.

Comment: Are you planning to extend your tokenizer/further parse the input or is it just that?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to handle this particular problem is using a regex in a loop.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\{.*?\\}|[^ \\{]+");
Matcher m = pat.matcher(source);
while (m.find()) {
    String token = m.group(0);
    // add to an ArrayList or whatever
}
```

The pattern looks for either:

- Left curly brace, followed by anything, followed by right curly brace.  (A backslash has to be inserted before the braces because otherwise they have special meaning.  `.*?` means match zero or more characters, with the `?` meaning as few as possible in case there are multiple `}` in the input.
- Any sequence of characters that isn't blank or `{`.

The loop will find each such token in turn; `m.group(0)` returns the string that was matched.

Using one regex makes it difficult to return a variable number of tokens.  Using `split` is often a good way to split a string into a variable number of tokens, but this case is a little too complicated to figure out the correct delimiter.  (I'm sure it's doable but would make your code harder to understand.)

I've tested this on the two input samples you provide, and I think it provides the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

This regex

```
    ^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\{.*\}).*$
```

works for your two given inputs, but will almost certainly fail for inputs whose (undeclared-in-question) syntax is valid.

If you'd be willing to accept a slight change to the input syntax, you might want to consider using json (and use java's parser for it, jackson: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)